# zabbix ldap login faild

Tags: php, centos, ldap, openldap, zabbix

i use zabbix and ldap. my config in Administration->Authentication is ok and test is pass. show in below picture 
[image: zabbix config is ok]

but when i want login with zabbix form the login is fail and say me user or pass is incorrect 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the users in Zabbix even if you use LDAP.

From the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/authentication):

> External LDAP authentication can be used to check user names and
>   passwords. Note that a user must exist in Zabbix as well, however its
>   Zabbix password will not be used.

Comment: thanks for your answer, did you have any solution for check also user name from Active directory?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: means in default way only password check from active directory. is that any way to check both username and password from active directory? change php zabbix code or any way?

Comment: Yes, the only way is to change the php code. There's a feature request to improve the AD/LDAP authentication by using groups and avoiding manual user creation (https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-276), but it's still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot one step. I've been looking for what's wrong, too. The test was fine, but the authorization was not.

Open the picture, there is the solution. I don't have 10 reputation and my picture is hidden.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSvEF.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32513825)